# What is the "derivative" of a family of submanifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

Suppose that $N(t)$ is a family of k-dimensional submanifolds in an n-dimensional manifold $M$, with $n > k$. Then $N(t)$ is a path in the space $\mathcal{M}$ of all k-dimensional submanifolds. I want to know, what is "$N'(t)$"?

If $r(t)$ is a curve in a manifold $M$, which is finite-dimensional, I can easily calculate it's derivative $r'(t)$. How would I get the analogous thing for $N(t)$ as in the situation above?

Some idea:

Suppose our family is $L_t = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : y = tx \}$ where $t$ is any number. Then maybe we can write:

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} L_t = \langle 0 , x \rangle $$

This vector field doesn't seem to be "normal" to the line though... So I'm not sure if that's correct.

Comment: It really depends what you mean by the space of all $k$-dimensional submanifolds. Is it a manifold, etc. etc... To some extent this sort of problem is dealt with in algebraic geometry anyway in moduli theory. But the derivative of such a path $r(t)$ at $t_0$ _should_ be something like a vector field along $r(t_0)\subset M$. (Along here means that the vectors lie in $T_pM$ for $p\in r(t_0)$, not just $T_p r(t_0)$.)

Comment: I think there are some "standard" topologies on spaces of submanifolds like this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195349/reference-request-topology-on-the-space-of-smooth-compact-submanifolds

Do you know of any examples where this kind of thing is talked about? Like a reference to the "moduli theory" you mentioned?

Comment: For an algebraic version of this you can look at the Hilbert scheme. This might take you far afield, though. I don't know much about those topologies like in Hirsch's book I'm afraid to say.

Comment: It is a vector field along a submanifold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The setting where I know it's defined is the one of *parameterized* submanifolds: You fix two manifolds $M$ and $N$ and consider the space of embeddings (or, more generally, smooth maps) maps $N\to M$. A *curve* in this space (or, a a 1-parameter family of submanifolds) is a smooth map $u: N\times [0,1]\to M$ such that for each $t$, $u(\cdot, t)$ is an embedding. Then the time-derivative of such a map is $u'(t)$, i.e. a vector field in $M$ along the submanifold $u(t)\subset M$.

There is also a version for families of *unparameterized*  submanifolds, in which case the derivative $N'(t)$ is a *section of of the normal bundle* of $N(t)\subset M$. If you know what the normal bundle (and a section) is, I can explain the details.

Edit. As requested, here is an explicit example. Consider the family of parameterized lines $u: (x,t)\mapsto (x,tx)$ in the plane, where $t$ is the time parameter of the family. (Each graph $y=tx$ is a line of the slope $t$.) The time-derivative of this family is
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)= (0,x). 
$$
Therefore, for each fixed $t$, the time derivative is the restriction to the line $y=tx$ of the vertical vector field $V(x,y)=(0,x)$.

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense. Could you add the details? I was thinking of an example, like if our family was a bunch of lines y = tx. Then this would be a family in R^2 or a surface in R^3 but I can't really figure out what the normal vector fields would be...

Comment: @Anon Later.........